# Requesting Facebook user analytics/ profile

Tags: facebook, analytics

I don't have a programming background. I intend to invite respondents to an online survey and their related Facebook usage will be very helpful. Other than being able to relate a user's usage data (hopefully derived from a permissions api)and a set of separate questions, I do not require additional user identification information eg photos, comments etc. Kindly assist on how to achieve this.

I hope the question is within your area of focus as I could not find a better alternative.

The usage data of interest include:

- Age & gender of user
- when they started using fb
- frequency of accessing various features (commenting, likes, photos)
- time spent on application
- number of friends, groups, etc

Do I need an app or it can b done from an fb page

Comment: Alternatively, which of the open existing apis can give some helpful information and how do I make use of it? Or can a developer provide some customised api?

Comment: I gathered that you can use the facebook graph api to make the needed 'calls' from your users. My implementation involves running a local 'xampp' server, and adding the facebook php sdk from github. php editor can netbeans, pdt tools, etc.  Now about hosting????? which is the best (easiest to deploy and cheap or free?) hosting platform since I need it up for a while?